# Finding the most repeated element from a table grouped by restrictions in sql

Tags: sql-server

In my code I have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE SERVICE
(
    SER_ID      INT primary key NOT NULL,
    SER_TYPE    VARCHAR(35)     NOT NULL,
    SER_STARTDATE DATE          NOT NULL,
    SER_ENDDATE   DATE,
    LAW_SOCNUM    VARCHAR(8),
    FOL_ID  INT,
    CLI_ID      INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (LAW_SOCNUM) REFERENCES LAWYER ON DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (FOL_ID) REFERENCES FEILD_OF_LAW ON DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (CLI_ID) REFERENCES CLIENT ON DELETE SET NULL,

);
```

and the table:

```
CREATE TABLE FEILD_OF_LAW
(
    FOL_ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    FOL_NAME VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL
);
```

My task is to find the name of the service that was the most common in the
given year which is just the field of law name. I am having trouble getting the correct value as calling max on FEILD_OF_LAW.FOL_NAME would only get me the one lowest alphabetically. Here is what I tried:

```
select distinct year(SER_STARTDATE) as 'YEAR', max(fol) as 'MOST_COMMON_SERV'
from SERVICE join (select SERVICE.SER_ID, FEILD_OF_LAW.FOL_NAME as 'fol'
    from SERVICE join FEILD_OF_LAW on SERVICE.FOL_ID = FEILD_OF_LAW.FOL_ID) a1 on SERVICE.SER_ID = a1.SER_ID 
group by year(SER_STARTDATE)
```

Can anyone please help me explain how to get the most repeated FOL_ID has appeared in the SERVICE table and how to group to its year. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than showing us table structure, it might help your question more to phrase it using sample input and output data.

Comment: For example, the value of (2016, civil), (2016, civil), (2016, family), (2017, Housing), (2017, crime), (2017, crime) would out put (2016, civil), (2017, crime)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use count aggregate function rather than max wit group by fol_id with top 1 it will return most repeated Fol_id with year.If you want t check all value then remove top 1 clause from query.

```
        select top 1 year(SER_STARTDATE) as 'YEAR', count(fol) as 
       'MOST_COMMON_SERV',fol
        from SERVICE join (select SERVICE.SER_ID, FEILD_OF_LAW.FOL_NAME as 'fol'
         from SERVICE join FEILD_OF_LAW on SERVICE.FOL_ID = FEILD_OF_LAW.FOL_ID) a1 
        on SERVICE.SER_ID = a1.SER_ID 
        group by year(SER_STARTDATE),fol
        order by count(fol) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a first-in-each group problem. Maybe try this:

```
with cte (the_year, the_count, the_fol_id, the_fol_name, row_num) AS (
    select datepart(year,ser_startDate), count(*), s.fol_id, fol_name,
        row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY datepart(year,ser_startDate) 
            ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rowNum
    from service s
        join feild_of_law f on f.fol_ID=s.fol_id
    group by datepart(year,ser_startDate), s.fol_id, fol_name
)
select *
    from cte 
where cte.row_num=1
```

The cte groups by the number of occurrences in each year and applies row numbers for each group and the second part selects the first row for each group.

Answer (score 0):

I read the other answer, but they have a problem: The result is correct only when you are approaching a single year. 
If you need the stats of more than one year, you could do this:

```
create view VW_ServiceStats as ( 

Select year(ser_startdate) as year, 
             fol.fol_name, 
            COUNT(*) as [Service Count]
from service ser 
inner join feild_of_law fol 
on ser.fol_id = fol.fol_id
group by  YEAR(ser.ser_startdate),fol.fol_name


)


Select YEAR , max(fol_name), MAX([service count])
from vw_servicestats
group by year
```

I have created a view which contains the first grouping ( year - fol - count ).
Then i selected only the more given service per year.

I think this way is also tidier than the others.